# How to run 2 commands at once in Jenkins with codeception and PhantomJS?

Tags: bash, jenkins, phantomjs, codeception, headless-browser

I would like to create a jenkins job for running, my acceptance tests with codeception on phantomjs.

So first I need to start the phantomjs headless server with

```
phantomjs --webdriver=4444
```

and now when this runs, I would run my tests with

```
php codecept.phar run acceptance
```

but when I define my jenkins job,
I add a shell script for those commands

BUT  when I run the first command: "phantomjs --webdriver=4444"
so the bash is stuck while running the command... so I cant run the next command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the phantomjs server in the background, otherwise it will not end (and hence your php command will never be reached):

```
phantomjs --webdriver=4444 &
php codecept.phar run acceptance
```

To end phantomjs afterwards, you could make use of `$!`, a special variable which contains the pid of the last process run in the background.

```
kill $!
```

Comment: is this safe? it wouldn't kill any other stuff if other stuff run on the background from other services?

Comment: `$!` contains the pid of the most recent process put into the background in the current shell. It won't be able to affect any processes from other shells (a shell script runs in its own shell). You could verify that nothing will be affected by putting a command like `jobs > jobs.txt` at the end of the script instead of the `kill` command. This will output a list of all the backgrounded processes in the current shell - only the `phantomjs` command should be listed.